# Python sort and delete duplicates in list an use re.sub

Tags: python, sed, python-re

I am total new with Python.
I try to make analog bash command: `cat domains.txt |sort -u|sed 's/^*.//g' > domains2.txt`
File domains contains list of domains with and without mask prefix `*.` like:

```
*.example.com
example2.org
```

About 300k+ lines

I wrote this code:

```
infile = "domains.txt"
outfile = "2"
outfile2 = "3"
with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
    for line in fin:
       line = line.replace('*.', "")
       fout.write(line)
with open('2', 'r') as r, open(outfile2, "w") as fout2 :
    for line in sorted(r):
        print(line, end='',file=fout2)
```

its cut `*.` as planned, sort list, but doesn't remove duplicates of lines

I had advise to use re.sub instead of replace to make pattern more strict (like in sed where I do it from beginning of lines), but when I tried this:

```
import re

infile = "domains.txt"
outfile = "2"
outfile2 = "3"
with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as fout:
    for line in fin:
       newline = re.sub('^*.', '', line)
       fout.write(newline)
with open('2', 'r') as r, open(outfile2, "w") as fout2 :
    for line in sorted(r):
        print(line, end='',file=fout2)
```

it just doesn't work with errors, which I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regular expressions `*`, `.` and alike are special characters. You should escape them in order to use them.

```
import re

s = "*.example.com"
re.sub(r'^\*\.', '', s)

> 'example.com'
```

Comment: thx, i just didt knew its work in same way as in shell with ```\```

Comment: now its work, but very interesting, cutting and sorting same file via shell and via python gave me different results. Source file have 391033 lines, after shell sorting+cutting i got 258604 lines, after this python scripts i got 242825 lines in result. Tomorrow will try to find what is difference